# Remove the second appearance of specific object in singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to remove the second appearance of specific object in singly linked list.

I have this code for my Node:

```
public class Node {
    Node next;

    Object data;

    public Node(Object _data)
    {
        next = null;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node(Object _data, Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
    }
}
```

And this is my function to remove:

```
public void removeSecondAppear(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++)
    {
        current = current.getNext();

        if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
        {
            if(found == true)
            {
                // remove element
                current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
                listCount--;
                break;
            }
            else if(found == false)
            {
                found = true;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

For some reason it won't remove the element. The method to find it works fine, but I don't know why it won't remove the element. I have a similar function to remove element of specific index which works fine:

```
public boolean remove(int index)
{
    if(index < 1 || index > size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Node current = head;

    for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
    {
        if(current.getNext() == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

    listCount--;

    return true;
}
```

I'm using the same methood, but it won't work in my method to remove the second appearance. Any help what I'm doin wron??

```
public int indexOf(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head.getNext();

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
        {
            return i;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

My implementation:

```
LinkedList LL = new LinkedList();

LL.add(1);
LL.add(2);
LL.add(3);
LL.add(4);
LL.add(4);
LL.add(5);
LL.removeSecondAppear("4");
```

My add method:

```
public void add(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    while(current.getNext() != null)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    current.setNext(temp);

    listCount++;
}
```

My constructor:

```
public LinkedList()
{
    head = new Node(null);
    listCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not find the index and then call your working remove method?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's a good option, I can use that method as well,  but since I already started with this I'm interested where is my mistake.

Comment: Small note: move this `current = current.getNext();` to the end of your loop. It's skipping over the head node without even checking anything. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @RyanJ yes, I have tried a lot of debugging, nothin worked :S, that line was originally at the end of the loop, but if i let it stay there, it errors on this line: `if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))`, saying NullPointerException when I call the function.

Comment: Also, I don't think your current is updating the actually memory locations to point to the next.

Comment: @user12831231 From what I can tell, I think that would indicate that the data in your head node is null. In that case, trying to call `.equals()` on it will produce an NPE.

Comment: @pmac89 What do you mean exactly? Can you explain, because I don't understand what the mistake is exactly.

Comment: @gla3dr I have tried with `Node current = head.getNext();` and the result is the same

Comment: Can you show the constructor for `LinkedList`? I from what you show here, it looks like data for `head` is always null.

Comment: @RyanJ Yes, I have added it, sorry about that

Comment: @user12831231 yep. that's exactly the problem. Your head node always has `null` data. If you are adding data to the list in such a fashion, you have a special case where the head node will always have null data, so you need to actually set (head.data = temp.data) on first insert. My example created a constructor that would automatically set the head node to a valid node value, hence why I see no issue. Fix your add to handle the head node and you're good.

Comment: @RyanJ Just checked my add function and it's the same as yours. Except that I create a Node with the data passed inside the function, and you take a Node as parameter which is the same I guess? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @RyanJ I got it I got it I got it... this little detail caused me a lot of pain and 2 days to find... now it makes the whole singly linked list a lot easier, since I know this little flaw I had in my class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is going to be found here (in a couple places):

As you loop through, you will keep advancing `current` until you find two instances where the data is equal and then remove it. Your remove won't work because you're not actually removing the node you want, it's the *next* node you're removing, which won't necessarily be equal because you've already iterated over the list and lost the previous equal node.

```
current = current.getNext();

if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
{
    if(found == true)
    {
        // remove element
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext()); // this isn't actually removing 'current'...
        listCount--;
        break;
    }
    else if(found == false)
    {
        found = true;
    }

}
```

First thing, you're not resetting found after not finding an equal node.
After the `if (equals)` block, add:

```
else {
    found = false;
}
```

Assuming you fix that, here's where you'd end up.
Take the following example:

```
[3] -> [4] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]
```

In your algorithm you will iterate over each element in this list like so:

Pass 1:

```
found = false
[3] -> [4] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]
 ^
 current 
 found = false
```

Pass 2:

```
found = false
[3] -> [4] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]
        ^
        current  
        found = true
```

Pass 3:

```
found = true
[3] -> [4] -> [4] -> [5] -> [6]
               ^
              current
```

When you get here, you are setting `current.next` to `current.next.next`, which is effectively removing `[5]` from the list, not 4. (consequently, this is also causing your NPE... consider the effects when you get to the end of the list and there is no `next.next`)

What you want to do is either find the index of your duplicate node and call your existing method to remove an element by the index, or keep a `previous` node to hold the value of the node that comes *before* `current` and when you remove, set `previous.setNext(current.getNext())` which will effectively delete `current`.

Second, you've made use of the `equals` method for `Object`, which uses the most discriminating method for determining equality, in that it will only return `true` for cases where the two compared objects refer to the same object. While this isn't necessarily a problem this can lead to issues depending on the type of data you store. Calling `equals` on any object will default to the closest implementation of `equals` for the actual type of data being represented by that object, so if it can't find one, it will default to `Object`s implementation, which will almost always give a false result if the objects are not the same.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Barring that, you might want to change how you compare object data, but I don't think that will really cause you too much of an issue.

Lastly, you will probably want to do some `null` checking and work your looping algorithm a bit, since this one will have problems if the duplicates are at the head of the list, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Here's a cut at a method that can help shed some light on what I've said:

```
public void removeSecondAppear(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;

    boolean found = false;

    while(current != null)
    {

        // for the sake of argument, let's say this will return true if you find equal data
        if( current.getData() != null && current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
        {
            if(found)
            {
                // remove element
                previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                listCount--;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                found = true;
            }

        }
        else {
            found = false;
        }

        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

}
```

Edit: I've written a small subset of a LinkedList implementation using the OP's `Node` class definition and used a small test to make sure my `removeSecondAppear` method works.

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = new Node(0);
    }
    public LinkedList(Node node) {
        head = node;
    }

    public void add(Node node) {
        Node ptr = head;
        while ( ptr.getNext() != null ) {
            ptr = ptr.getNext();
        }
        ptr.setNext(node);
    }

    ... /// added removeSecondAppear here, but left out to keep it short(er)

    // provided a print() method
}
```

Using this test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(new Node(1));
        list.add(new Node(2));
        list.add(new Node(4));
        list.add(new Node(4));
        list.add(new Node(5));
        list.print();

        list.removeSecondAppearance(4);
        list.print();
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
1 2 4 4 5 
1 2 4 5
```

Comment: On the first pass, should the second `found` be equal to false?

Comment: How exactly do I call the function remove, if I find the index though? I have thought of that before, but since 'current' is a node, and the remove is a function from the linked list, how can I call it?

Comment: This is true, he needs to set the previous element to the next element.

Comment: Though again, he's comparing memory locations, not actual type data.

Comment: @RyanJ I have tried the test code you provided, and it errors at `if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))` with NullPointerException again, could .equals be a problem here? What else can I use to compare the data?

Comment: @pmac89 I don't disagree with what you say, but in fact if the object he's comparing equality to has an `equals` implementation, it will default to that before going up the chain. I agree some better code, such as generics, needs to go into his `Node` implementation, but I think the error is much more basic than that.

Comment: @user12831231 did you actually initialize your list with any data? If the `Object` data is null, then this will surely fail...

Comment: @RyanJ You are absolutely right. Now if he's comparing Objects such as a Player (a subclass of Object) then your method is right.

Comment: @RyanJ My list has the following elements: `1 2 3 4 4 5`, in total 6. I add them manually before I call the function. I call the function for `4`.

Comment: @user12831231 we'd have to see your code to help further. I just wrote a small implementation of what I've suggested, using your `Node` class and my own add method. Using integer data, I get no issue.

Comment: @RyanJ I have added it. Is it require to do `new Node(1)` when doing the add? Does my method of `LL.add(1)` is not correct?

Comment: @user12831231 no it's fine, you're doing the `new Node()` in your method, I'm not.

Comment: @RyanJ So, what exactly am I doing wrong in here? I've checked my code a few times and everything you've done is the same with my code, or did I miss something? I still get error on the `if(...equals..)` line.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to pmac89's answer, it would be better if you genericized your node class so that you can use the proper `.equals()` method for the type of your data:

```
public class Node<T> {
    Node<T> next;

    T data;

    ...

}
```

From that point essentially you can replace `Object` with `T` and `Node` with `Node<T>`. When you create a node, you specify its type. Then, say you make a `Node<String>`. When you call `.equals()` on the data, it will use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) <strike>instead of [`Object.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).</strike>

The reason you don't want to call `Object.equals()` is, as pmac89 said, because you are checking *if they are the same object*. What you really want to check is *whether they have the same value*.

Edit:
As Ryan J mentioned, if your data is a subclass of `Object`, it will default to the `equals()` implementation for that type, if there is one.

Here's the generics tutorial if you aren't familiar with them:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is your Node class....

In

```
public class Node {
     ...
     Object data;
     ....
}
```

So when you are calling

```
if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
```

in your removeSecondAppear, they will not equal. Remember, Object.equal() on an object is comparing memory locations. None of the list items will equal each other, only the item itself.

EDIT: Also you would want

`previous.setNext(current.getNext())` //Oops, fixed a mistake here too!!!

EDIT 2: 
Also you are not excluding the thing you are looking for, so you are finding itself. To elaborate on this, think of it this way;

I have the list 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5. How many times does it find 4? I am guessing once. The reason being is that each of the list items has an address that does not match the other, as this is saying data is an Object which is assigned a place in memory. So when you call the Object.equals(someOtherObject) you are asking if they have the same location in memory. They do not have the same location in memory. The reason why you are only finding 1 second appearance in your check during the removeSecondAppear is because you are going through the whole list again and not excluding the node that you are looking for.